# Showing exponentiation with real exponents is well-defined

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, exponentiation

So I was attempting to derive the exponentiation rules for real exponents, taking as a starting point the exponentiation rules for *rational* exponents. I began by defining $a^x = \lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} a^{x_n}$, where $a, x$ are real numbers (with $a > 0$), and $x_n$ is a sequence of rational numbers that converges to $x$.

Now, to show that this operation is well-defined, I considered another sequence, $x_n'$, that also converges to $x$, and tried to show that $\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} a^{x_n} = \lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} a^{x_n'}$, by showing that:

\begin{equation}
    \lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \frac{a^{x_n}}{a^{x_n'}} = 1
  \end{equation}

From the properties of rational exponentiation, I can rewrite the quotient as $a^{x_n - x_n'}$, and of course that intuitively, one can see that as $n$ gets ever larger, $x_n$ and $x_n'$ get ever closer, and so $a^{x_n - x_n'}$ can get arbitrarily close to $1$.

My question, though, is: how would one prove this *formally*? I.e., let us write the limit condition ($\varepsilon$ is real, $p, n$ are a positive integers):

\begin{equation}
    \forall \varepsilon > 0 \; \exists p \; \colon n \ge p \Rightarrow \lvert a^{x_n - x_n'} - 1 \rvert < \varepsilon
  \end{equation}

How would one, given an $\varepsilon$, proceed to produce a $p$ such that for $n\ge p$, the consequent of the implication holds?

Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: It doesn’t follow the same structure as your argument but for another reference see one of the first problems in Baby Rudin Chap 1.

Comment: I have explained this approach to exponentiation in my blog post: https://paramanands.blogspot.com/2014/05/theories-of-exponential-and-logarithmic-functions-part-3.html?m=0

Comment: Another nice resource for this is Bartle's "The Elements of Real Analysis", which was my Intro to Real Analysis textbook. In addition to its usual problem set, the text has several "Projects", sets of problems building to some particular bit of theory. Some of those projects consisted of various approaches to defining exponentiation and trigonometric function and developing their key properties. This approach was one. Though they were never assigned by the teacher, I did all of those projects, and they greatly helped my understanding of higher mathematics.